# Ruby: How to escape url with square brackets [ and ]?

Tags: ruby, url, escaping

This url:

```
http://gawker.com/5953728/if-alison-brie-and-gillian-jacobs-pin-up-special-doesnt-get-community-back-on-the-air-nothing-will-[nsfw]
```

should be:

```
http://gawker.com/5953728/if-alison-brie-and-gillian-jacobs-pin-up-special-doesnt-get-community-back-on-the-air-nothing-will-%5Bnsfw%5D
```

But when I pass the first one into `URI.encode`, it doesn't escape the square brackets. I also tried `CGI.escape`, but that escapes all the '/' as well.

What should I use to escape URLS properly? Why doesn't `URI.encode` escape square brackets?

Comment: See section "2.2. Reserved Characters" of the [URI RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt). `[` and `]` are not special so they don't need to be encoded.

Comment: Actually [RFC 2732](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2732.txt) moves `[` and `]` to _reserved_ characters because of new IPv6 syntax. Thus they should not be used in URI paths.

"This document updates the generic syntax for Uniform Resource
   Identifiers defined in RFC 2396 [URL].  It defines a syntax for IPv6
   addresses and allows the use of "[" and "]" within a URI explicitly
   for this reserved purpose."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`encode` doesn't escape brackets because they aren't special -- they have no special meaning in the path part of a URI, so they don't actually need escaping.

If you want to escape chars other than just the "unsafe" ones, pass a second arg to the encode method.   That arg should be a regex matching, or a string containing, every char you want encoded (*including* chars the function would otherwise already match!).

Comment: This won't work actually.  A URI.encode(uri, "[]") will only encode the brackets.  Given `test.com/[bracket] with spaces/` the spaces aren't encoded and an `open(encoded_uri)` will throw `URI::InvalidURIError` errors.  The problem is that you'll end up in a catch-22 if you escape and then encode or encode and then escape, because there will always be one version of the URL that doesn't work.

Comment: @yekta: That's what the bit at the end, "(_including_ chars the function would otherwise already match!)", means.

Answer (score 22):

You can escape `[` with `%5B` and `]` with `%5D`.

Your URL will be:

```
URL.gsub("[","%5B").gsub("]","%5D")
```

I don't like that solution but it's working.

Comment: Agreed, I don't like it either but it works.  This actually isn't the correct solution to his question though, if you update it to include `URI.encode(url).gsub("[","%5B").gsub("]","%5D")` I can upvote.

Answer (score 6):

If using a third-party gem is an option, try [addressable](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable).

```
require "addressable/uri"

url = Addressable::URI.parse("http://[::1]/path[]").normalize!.to_s
#=> "http://[::1]/path%5B%5D"
```

Note that the normalize! method will not only escape invalid characters but also perform casefolding on the hostname part, unescaping on unnecessarily escaped characters and the like:

```
uri = Addressable::URI.parse("http://Example.ORG/path[]?query[]=%2F").normalize!
url = uri.to_s #=> "http://example.org/path%5B%5D?query%5B%5D=/"
```

So, if you just want to normalize the path part, do as follows:

```
uri = Addressable::URI.parse("http://Example.ORG/path[]?query[]=%2F")
uri.path = uri.normalized_path
url = uri.to_s #=> "http://Example.ORG/path%5B%5D?query[]=%2F"
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [new IP-v6 syntax](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2732.txt) there could be urls like this:

```
http://[1080:0:0:0:8:800:200C:417A]/index.html
```

Because of this we should escape [] only after host part of the url:

```
if url =~ %r{\[|\]}
  protocol, host, path = url.split(%r{/+}, 3)
  path = path.gsub('[', '%5B').gsub(']', '%5D') # Or URI.escape(path, /[^\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;\/?:@&%=+$,]/)
  url = "#{protocol}//#{host}/#{path}"
end
```