# Spark cannot read file with Square Brackets `[]` in the file path?

Tags: apache-spark

Environment(s):

- Azure blob storage and Local File System
- Scala 2.12.10/Spark 3.0.1

With a file existing at C:\path\to\any\file-with-[brackets].csv,

`spark.read.csv("C:\\path\\to\\any\\file-with-[brackets].csv")`

results in

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: file:/C:/path/to/any/file-with-[brackets].csv;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:621)
...
```

If I remove the brackets both from the file and the path string, no problem:

`spark.read.csv("C:\\path\\to\\any\\file-without-brackets.csv")`

results in

```
csv: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_c0: string]
```

(I cannot believe this hasn't been seen before, I find no mention of it on google or stackoverflow.)

How do you reference a file with brackets in the filename in Spark?

UPDATE ! I discovered that brackets are used in the glob syntax of spark's file pathing (you can use wildcards in spark file paths, and [1234] looks for any character 1, 2, 3, or 4 in the position in the file path, like a REGEX)... But I cannot figure out how to ESCAPE a bracket in this context.

How do you escape Spark Wildcard functionality around square brackets when referencing a singular file with literal square brackets in a file path with spark's DataFrameReader?

Answer (score 1):

Similar kind of issue in hadoop has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60000928/uploading-file-with-square-brackets-in-its-name-to-hadoop-via-hadoop-fs-put.%20%20%20Spark%20also%20used%20hadoop%20libraries%20to%20read%20files.).

Spark uses hadoop libraries to read files. If you look at the stack trace and check the line which throwing the message, it points to `checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary` method of [Datasource.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/DataSource.scala) file. Internally `getUri` method is getting called, may be issue is occurring there. We can escape `[ with %5B and ] with %5D` as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13013987/ruby-how-to-escape-url-with-square-brackets-and/17901435), but this is incase of URL. Not sure how to achieve this in string as csv() or load() method accepts string not URI.

Comment: It's because it's expecting regex notation inside the brackets to allow more precise glob'ing, so they aren't interpreted as part of the path.